# Recursively search directories beginning with string for inner directories matching pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to find all directories the name's of which are five digits within directories beginning with a certain string, in this example: `test`. The directory structure is like:

```
   |-1
     |---12324
   |-otherFile
     |---23424
   |-someFile
     |---22343
   |-test
     |---22343
     |---23424
   |-testTemp
     |---23454
     |---adsf
   |-testTemp1
     |---34566
   |-testTemp2
     |---34543
```

I would like to get the 5 digit names only in the folders that begin with test, ignoring the directories `1`, `otherFile`, and `someFile`.

I'm trying something like this:

```
find ./test* d -name "\d+" print
```

which gives the error

> `find: print: unknown primary or operator`

or

```
grep -r "./test*/\d{5}"
```

which gives the error

> `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin`

What do these errors mean? How can I make this search? Also it would be nice if the directories the files were in were printed too. I am in the Mac Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `-regex` optin in `find`:

```
find ./test -regextype posix-egrep -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]{5}$'
```

On OSX use:

```
find -E ./test -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]{5}$'
```

Or without regex:

```
find ./test -type d -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I get the error: `find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Ah, and the second, by adding an asterisk, that works great. `find ./test* -type d -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`. Why can't I use the regex one I wonder.

Comment: If you're using OSX then use: `find -E ./test -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]{5}$'`

Comment: Perfect. To improve performance is there any way to limit the searches for the `\d{5}` to one layer after the `test` directory?

Comment: Using `find -E ./test* -type d -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[0-9]{5}$' works

Comment: Right, to restrict level `-maxdepth 1` is the correct option

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this (should exist a simpler version) :

```
find . -type d -name "test*" | xargs -I % sh -c 'find % -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*[0-9]\{5\}"'
```

First, look for test* folders with `find`

```
find . -type d -name "test*"
```

Then, from the first find result, use `xargs` to find  the 5 digits folder using regex sed :

```
find % -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*[0-9]\{5\}"
```

This means, I want anything `.*` which ends with 5 digits exactly `[0-9]\{5\}`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I get the error: `find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator`.

Comment: A good answer is not one that works, it's an answer that works *and* is explained properly so the OP can understand the solution. Add an explanation and your answer will be more likely to be upvoted.